# Inverse Laplace Transform of $e^{-as}(\frac{1}{s^2}- \frac{1}{s^2+1})$

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm having troubles finding the inverse laplace transform of
$$e^{-as}\left({1\over s^2} - {1\over {s^2+1}}\right)$$
where $a$ is a constant of-course.
Help with explanations would be appreciated!

Comment: You should already know the inverse transforms of the terms inside the parentheses, since they are standard. The multiplication by the exponential becomes a translation in the $t$ domain, also standard stuff. Where does your difficulty lie?

Comment: the inverse laplace of 1/s^2 is 't'. the inverse of 1/(s^2+1) is 'sin(t)'.
my difficulty is the multiplication by the exponential.

Comment: Where does this question come from? Is it from a course assignment?

Comment: No, this question comes from past years exam.
 I'm having a final exam in a week in differential equations, but I was missing half of the course because my wife is about to deliver. so basically, I'm new to this material.

I was looking for similar solutions around the net, but couldn't find any helpful.

Comment: It's unreadable.
anyway, I have the solution for this. I wanna know how to find it myself.

Comment: Having trouble getting the formula typeset correctly.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(s)e^{-at}\right\}
=\left[\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\right]_{t\to t-a}U(t-a)$
where $U$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: Thank you! what is the meaning of this? [L−1F(s)]t→t−a

Comment: You take the inverse transform of $F(s)$ and then replace every occurrence of $t$ with $(t-a)$

Comment: It works! thank you!
I got: $U(t-a)\times{(t-a-sin(t))}$
The best part is now I understand how to get this formula from the formulas given to us in the exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(s)e^{-as}\right\}
=\left[\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\}\right]_{t\to t-a}U(t-a)$

For example

$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{se^{-\pi s}}{s^2+1}\right\}=\cos(t-\pi)U(t-\pi)$$

Comment: Thank you so much!
So in my case the solution is: $U(t−a)\times{(t−a−sin(t))}$

Comment: No, both occurrences of $t$ must be replaced with $t-a$, so also $\sin(t-a)$.

Comment: I don’t understand your notation $[\quad]_{t\to t-a}$

Comment: @let'shaveabreakdown In the comments of my question you can see he explained:
"You take the inverse transform of F(s) and then replace every occurrence of t with (t−a)"

Answer (score 1):

> **Second Shifting Property:** If $~\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(p)\right\}
> =f(t)~$, then $~\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(p)~e^{-ap}\right\}
> =g(t)~$ where $$~g(t)=\begin{cases}  f(t-a) \quad \text{if} ~~~t~\gt~a\\ 0 \quad ~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{if} ~~~t~\lt ~a\end{cases}~$$

Here we have to find $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{e^{-as}\left({1\over s^2} - {1\over {s^2+1}}\right)\right\}
$$

Here $$F(s)={1\over s^2} - {1\over {s^2+1}}$$

So $$f(t)=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(s)\right\}
=t-\sin t$$as $~\mathcal{L}(t)=\frac{1}{s^2}~$and $~\mathcal{L}(\sin at)=\frac{a}{a^2+s^2}~$

Hence $$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{e^{-as}\left({1\over s^2} - {1\over {s^2+1}}\right)\right\}=\begin{cases}  (t-a)~-~\sin(t-a) \quad \text{if} ~~~t~\gt~a\\ 0 \quad ~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{if} ~~~t~\lt ~a\end{cases}~
$$